# Malformed id error while creating item inside inplace archive mailbox

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

> I am trying to create an item inside inplace archive mailbox in exchange online using
>   CreateItem class in EWS but I am getting malformed id error for folder
>   although folderId is correct. (I am using the same soap request that I
>   use for creating items inside other folders like inbox, sendItems and
>   all)

Comment: You need to show the code your using,

Comment: For normal mailbox, I am able to restore an email but for inplace enabled mailbox,  I was having this problem.

Comment: So show the code the using, its very hard to help you otherwise